# when defining "fluid solid interface" in transient structural, the question mark keeps showing

Tags: transient, ansys, fsi

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fefKh.png)

G'day, mates. I met a problem that I couldn't figure out. I built a simple model consisting of a cylinder(solid) and a cuboid(fluid) for simulating Kármán vortex street. And the cylinder is submerged in the fluid, so the entire surface of it should be selected in the Scope dialog box. But there is a blue question mark beside the icon of "Fluid Solid Interface." I don't know why. Any mistake did I make?

I hope someone can help me out; thanks. Oh btw, I'm a beginner.

To make the question mark vanish so that I can go on.

Answer (score 0):

Once clicked “solve”, immediately received a warning message saying that if the stiffness behaviour of the body is set “rigid”, then it’ll cause invalid “Fluid Solid Interface”. So just set it to be “flexible”. Okay, this problem has been solved!